# how to use phpexcel in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, phpexcel, zend-autoloader

I need to import data from excel,And the I decided to use PHPExcel,But when I require it in my web , a few warnings occured :

```
      Warning: 
    include_once(PHPExcel\Shared\ZipStreamWrapper.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\www\LearningCenter\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 146
```

here is my code.:

```
public function getUserFromExcel($path){
    echo $path;
    require_once 'Excel/PHPExcel.php'; 
    echo $path;
}
```

and my webapp structre is :

library
 Zend
 Excel
 others-thirdpart-library

it seems that there is something wrong with the autoloader.

I read a few articles But did not find a solution.

My final aim is to read date from an excel file:
can some one give me some sugestion on ether how to use phpexcel in zend or how to import data from excel useing zend itself.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy the PHPExcel library into your `/library` directory, the structure should be as follows

```
/library
    /PHPExcel
    /PHPExcel.php
```

and then add this in your application.ini

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "PHPExcel_"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "PHPExcel"
```

and it should work.

Comment: I just solved the problem before I see your answer. But thanks. lol.   by the way, the only thing I did is move the PHPExcel folder and PHPExcel.php file directly  into Library. And I did not add autoloaderNamespaces[] in my application.ini .  thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Add your lib to library folder. (libarary/PHPExcel)

Add new `autoloaderNamespaces.phpexcel = "PHPExcel_"`

You can use library method using `PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);`

Comment: I just solved the problem before I see your answer. But thanks. lol.   by the way, the only thing I did is move the PHPExcel folder and PHPExcel.php file directly  into Library. And I did not add autoloaderNamespaces[] in my application.ini .  thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to autoload PHPExcel classes. 
I suggest to avoid to have problems with autoload PHPExcel classes to use the zf2 module [MvlabsPHPExcel](https://github.com/mvlabs/MvlabsPHPExcel) that will give you an easy integration of [PHPOffice/PHPExcel][2] library into zend framework 2.